# How to write more than once in an XML document

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2007

I'm trying to save a `word` and a `boolean` value, that I have in an array of records, to an XML document. This is my code:

```
procedure AddArrayToXMLFile(const Array : array of TKeycodeRecord; const Name : string);
var
  XMLFile : IXMLDocument;
  NameNode, ArrayFieldNode: IXMLNode;
  i : integer;
begin
  if FileExists(ArrayXMLFilePath) then
  begin
    XMLFile := LoadXMLDocument(ArrayXMLFilePath);
  end
  else
  begin
    XMLFile := NewXMLDocument;
    NameNode := XMLFile.AddChild(Name);
    ArrayFieldNode := NameNode.AddChild('child');
  end;

  for i := 0 to Length(Array) - 1 do
  begin
    ArrayFieldNode.Attributes['keycode'] := Array[i].keycode;
    ArrayFieldNode.Attributes['shiftState'] := Array[i].shiftState;
  end;

  XMLFile.SaveToFile(ArrayXMLFilePath);
end;
```

And this is the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestName><child keycode="48" shiftState="false"/></TestName>
```

The procedure saves only the last entry of the array, which makes me believe that the `for loop` only changes the values of the first entry, instead of adding more values to the XML document. The wanted result would look like this, but with more entries:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestName><child keycode="52" shiftState="false"/></TestName>
<TestName><child keycode="70" shiftState="true"/></TestName>
<TestName><child keycode="75" shiftState="false"/></TestName>
<TestName><child keycode="49" shiftState="false"/></TestName>
<TestName><child keycode="48" shiftState="false"/></TestName>
```

or like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestName><child keycode="48" shiftState="false"/><child keycode="49" shiftState="false"/><child keycode="48" shiftState="false"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the nodes **NameNode** and **ArrayFieldNode** in the for loop, like that:

```
procedure AddArrayToXMLFile(const Array : array of TKeycodeRecord; const Name : string);
var
  XMLFile : IXMLDocument;
  NameNode, ArrayFieldNode: IXMLNode;
  i : integer;
begin
  if FileExists(ArrayXMLFilePath) then
  begin
    XMLFile := LoadXMLDocument(ArrayXMLFilePath);
  end
  else
  begin
    XMLFile := NewXMLDocument;
  end;

  NameNode := XMLFile.AddChild(Name);

  for i := 0 to Length(Array) - 1 do
  begin      
    ArrayFieldNode := NameNode.AddChild('child');
    ArrayFieldNode.Attributes['keycode'] := Array[i].keycode;
    ArrayFieldNode.Attributes['shiftState'] := Array[i].shiftState;
  end;

  XMLFile.SaveToFile(ArrayXMLFilePath);
end;
```

The way you did is you added a single node and then in the loop you  changed the attributes of the same node in each iteration.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed with 1 correction. Your initial solution has 1 problem. The line ```NameNode := XMLFile.AddChild(Name);``` should be out of the loop. With it in the loop the program broke and said that XML documents can only have 1 top level element. But if you take that line out of the loop and put it on the line above it, then it works. Please change that in your answer, so I can accept it as the correct one.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It needs to be a single root node. I accepted your edit. Thanks. But now, the result doesn't look like the one you wanted in your OP. It looks like that: `<TestName><child.. /> <child.. /> <child.. /></TestName>`. So either you have the xml in this format, or add another top level node (`RootNode := XMLFile.AddChild('Root');`), and put in the loop like that: `RootNode.AddChild(NameNode);`. This way the result will look like the one you wanted it the OP:  `<Root><TestName><child../></TestName><TestName><child../></TestName><TestName><child../></TestName></Root>`

Comment: You are right. It does look like that but that isn't a problem. I gave the example because that's one of the ways I wanted it to look, but the way it is now, is also useful, which is why I accepted the answer. My problem was writing multiple records from an array, not receiving multiple lines. I'm going to edit my question as well, so it makes better sense.